# Adding API generated PID to URL with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have an url created through an API which contains eg:

```
pid=b4b17703-0e95-41ff-8679-ebee06c67408
```

What I need is to add `b4b17703-0e95-41ff-8679-ebee06c67408`to the given url since its not the same number each time.

Can anyone point me in the direction I need to go, I would be forever greatful.

I need to do this with Javascript if possible :)

Comment: does "pid" come back from the json as an object? or in a string

Comment: It comes back as an object from the server :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `pid` comes back as an object from the API, then you can do:

```
response = fromApi();
location.href = location.href + response.pid;
```

If the `pid` comes back in a string, then you can do:

```
response = fromApi();
pid = response.theObject.split('pid=')[1];
location.href = location.href + pid;
```

Please note that the above code is just pseudo-code aimed at helping you achieve the results you desire. I have no idea of your code base.